# Преобразовать структуру данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть структура данных следующего содержания:

```
anno_data=[['Item1', 'Rectangle', 'label1', '018', '[276, 22]', '[18.0, 21.0]'],
 ['Item1', 'Polygon', 'label1', '018', '[[199.0, 179.0], [200.0, 179.0], [201.0, 179.0], [202.0, 179.0], [203.0, 179.0], [204.0, 179.0], [207.0, 211.0], [206.0, 211.0], [205.0, 211.0], [204.0, 211.0], [203.0, 211.0], [202.0, 211.0], [201.0, 211.0], [200.0, 211.0], [199.0, 211.0], [198.0, 211.0], [197.0, 211.0], [195.0, 210.0], [194.0, 209.0], [192.0, 207.0], [191.0, 206.0], [192.0, 206.0]]', ''],
           ['Item1', 'Point', 'label1', '018', '[380, 171]', ''],
           ['Item2', 'Rectangle', 'label1', '032', '[67, 80]', '[39.0, 46.0]']]
```

Видно, что это список списков. И в каждом списке на третьей позиции есть элементы '018' и '032'.
На эти элементы нужно завязаться и на их основе создать следующую структуру

```
{
"032": {
    "filename": "032",
    "regions": {
        "0": {
            "shape_attributes": {
                "name": "Rectangle",
                "x": 67,
                "y": 80,
                "width": 39.0,
                "height": 46.0
            },
            "region_attributes": {
                "label": "label1"
            }
        }
    }
},
"018": {
    "filename": "018",
    "regions": {
        "0": {
            "shape_attributes": {
                "name": "Rectangle",
                "x": 276,
                "y": 22,
                "width": 18.0,
                "height": 21.0
            },
            "region_attributes": {
                "label": "label1"
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "shape_attributes": {
                "name": "Point",
                "cx": 380,
                "cy": 171
            },
            "region_attributes": {
                "label": "label1"
            }
        }
       
    }
}   
}
```

Мой код

```
def get_w_h(str_wh):
    to_lst = list(eval(str_wh))
    return to_lst

def all_x_y(fig, coords):
    to_lst = list(eval(coords))
    if fig == 'Point':
        return [[to_lst[0]], [to_lst[1]]]
    else:
        x = to_lst[0]
        y = to_lst[1]
        return x,y


dic=dict()
uniq=set([l1[3] for l1 in anno_data])
for k in uniq:
    dic[k]=[]

med_d={}

for i in anno_data:
    it=0
    dic_sh_att = {}
    dic_reg_att={}
    if i[3] in dic:
        if i[1]=='Rectangle':
            dic_sh_att['name'] = i[1]
            dic_sh_att['x'] = all_x_y(i[1], i[4])[0]
            dic_sh_att['y'] = all_x_y(i[1], i[4])[1]
            dic_sh_att['width']=get_w_h(i[5])[1]
            dic_sh_att['height']= get_w_h(i[5])[0]
    
        else:
            dic_sh_att['name'] = i[1]
            dic_sh_att['cx'] = all_x_y(i[1], i[4])[0]
            dic_sh_att['cy'] = all_x_y(i[1],i[4])[1]
        dic_reg_att["label"] = i[2]
        dic_reg_att["class"]=str(it)
        med_d[it]={"shape_attributes":dic_sh_att,
              "region_attributes": dic_reg_att}
        dic[i[3]].append(med_d)
        it += 1
```

Но результат не тот. Не могу сообразить как правильно сделать. Помогите плз

Comment: И еще нужен результат, который из Polygone должен получиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам запилил. Если у кого есть решение поизященее, буду рад

```
dic=dict()
uniq=set([l1[3] for l1 in anno_data])
for k in uniq:
    dic[k]=[]

it=0
for i in anno_data:
    med_d={}
    dic_sh_att = {}
    dic_reg_att={}
    if i[3] in dic:
        if i[1]=='Rectangle':
            dic_sh_att['name'] = i[1]
            dic_sh_att['x'] = all_x_y(i[1], i[4])[0]
            dic_sh_att['y'] = all_x_y(i[1], i[4])[1]
            dic_sh_att['width']=get_w_h(i[5])[1]
            dic_sh_att['height']= get_w_h(i[5])[0]
        elif i[1] == 'Polygon':
             dic_sh_att['name'] = i[1]
             dic_sh_att['all_points_x'] = all_x_y(i[1], i[4])[0]
             dic_sh_att['all_points_y'] = all_x_y(i[1],i[4])[1]
        else:
            dic_sh_att['name'] = i[1]
            dic_sh_att['cx'] = all_x_y(i[1], i[4])[0]
            dic_sh_att['cy'] = all_x_y(i[1],i[4])[1]
    dic_reg_att["label"] = i[2]
    dic_reg_att["class"]=str(it)
    if i[3] in dic:
        if dic[i[3]]:
            it+=1
            med_d[it]={"shape_attributes":dic_sh_att,
            "region_attributes": dic_reg_att}
        else:
            it=0
            med_d[it]={"shape_attributes":dic_sh_att,
            "region_attributes": dic_reg_att}

        dic[i[3]].append(med_d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Код для формирования результата для `Polygon` сделал по коду в вашем ответе, надеюсь, что правильно понял. Если что-то неправильно, добавьте пример результата для `Polygon` в вопрос.

```
import ast

from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

anno_data=[['Item1', 'Rectangle', 'label1', '018', '[276, 22]', '[18.0, 21.0]'],
           ['Item1', 'Polygon', 'label1', '018', '[[199.0, 179.0], [200.0, 179.0], [201.0, 179.0], [202.0, 179.0], [203.0, 179.0], [204.0, 179.0], [207.0, 211.0], [206.0, 211.0], [205.0, 211.0], [204.0, 211.0], [203.0, 211.0], [202.0, 211.0], [201.0, 211.0], [200.0, 211.0], [199.0, 211.0], [198.0, 211.0], [197.0, 211.0], [195.0, 210.0], [194.0, 209.0], [192.0, 207.0], [191.0, 206.0], [192.0, 206.0]]', ''],
           ['Item1', 'Point', 'label1', '018', '[380, 171]', ''],
           ['Item2', 'Rectangle', 'label1', '032', '[67, 80]', '[39.0, 46.0]']]


d = defaultdict(lambda : dict(regions=dict()))

for row in anno_data:
    file_data = d[row[3]]
    file_data['filename'] = row[3]
    
    regions = file_data['regions']
    
    if row[1] == 'Rectangle':
        # Вытаскиваем список из строки с помощью literal_eval, и сразу распаковываем в отдельные переменные
        x, y = ast.literal_eval(row[4])
        width, height = ast.literal_eval(row[5])
        shape_attributes = dict(
            name=row[1],
            x=x,
            y=y,
            width=width,
            height=height
        )
    elif row[1] == 'Point':
        x, y = ast.literal_eval(row[4])
        shape_attributes = dict(
            name=row[1],
            cx=x,
            cy=y
        )
    elif row[1] == 'Polygon':
        points = ast.literal_eval(row[4])
        # zip тут превращает большой список из маленьких списков по 2 элемента в два длинных списка
        # (один для x координат, другой для y), и дальше эти два списка распаковываем в отдельные переменные
        all_points_x, all_points_y = zip(*points)
        shape_attributes = dict(
            name=row[1],
            all_points_x=all_points_x,
            all_points_y=all_points_y
        )
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Неизвестная фигура: {row[1]}")
    
    # Вычисление следующего индекса: максимальное целочисленное значение ключа + 1, или 0, если еще ничего нет
    index = max(map(int, regions.keys()), default=-1) + 1
    regions[str(index)] = dict(
        shape_attributes=shape_attributes,
        region_attributes=dict(label=row[2])
    )

# Если обязательно нужен словарь, а не defaultdict, то выполнить следующую строчку:
d = dict(d)


# json только для красивого вывода
import json
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
```

Результат:

```json
{
    "018": {
        "regions": {
            "0": {
                "shape_attributes": {
                    "name": "Rectangle",
                    "x": 276,
                    "y": 22,
                    "width": 18.0,
                    "height": 21.0
                },
                "region_attributes": {
                    "label": "label1"
                }
            },
            "1": {
                "shape_attributes": {
                    "name": "Polygon",
                    "all_points_x": [
                        199.0,
                        200.0,
                        201.0,
                        202.0,
                        203.0,
                        204.0,
                        207.0,
                        206.0,
                        205.0,
                        204.0,
                        203.0,
                        202.0,
                        201.0,
                        200.0,
                        199.0,
                        198.0,
                        197.0,
                        195.0,
                        194.0,
                        192.0,
                        191.0,
                        192.0
                    ],
                    "all_points_y": [
                        179.0,
                        179.0,
                        179.0,
                        179.0,
                        179.0,
                        179.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        211.0,
                        210.0,
                        209.0,
                        207.0,
                        206.0,
                        206.0
                    ]
                },
                "region_attributes": {
                    "label": "label1"
                }
            },
            "2": {
                "shape_attributes": {
                    "name": "Point",
                    "cx": 380,
                    "cy": 171
                },
                "region_attributes": {
                    "label": "label1"
                }
            }
        },
        "filename": "018"
    },
    "032": {
        "regions": {
            "0": {
                "shape_attributes": {
                    "name": "Rectangle",
                    "x": 67,
                    "y": 80,
                    "width": 39.0,
                    "height": 46.0
                },
                "region_attributes": {
                    "label": "label1"
                }
            }
        },
        "filename": "032"
    }
}
```